# loading ResourceDictionary from baml using Baml2006Reader

Tags: wpf, baml, baml2006reader

How do can I read through a baml stream that contains a `ResourceDictionaory` using the `Baml2006Reader` and without acually instantiating the the `ResourceDictionary`?

I can ready through regular baml that just contains a UserControl just fine and I can examine the XAML tree using `Baml2006Reader.NodeType` etc.

But once the reader hits a `ResourceDictionary`, `Baml2006Reader.Member.Name` is `"DeferrableContent"` and  `Baml2006Reader.Value` contains a `MemoryStream` that can not be parsed by another instance of `Baml2006Reader`. I can't event instantiate the reader:

> System.IO.EndOfStreamException occurred   HResult=-2147024858
>   Message=Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.MemoryStream.InternalReadInt32()
>          at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_Header()
>          at WpfApplication10.AssemblyExtensions.Read(Stream stream, List`1 result) in d:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication10\WpfApplication10\AssemblyExtensions.cs:line
>   84   InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that whenever the Baml2006Reader encounters an element where `Baml2006Reader.Member.Name` is `"DeferrableContent"` it is followed by another node where `BamlReader.Value` is a `MemoryStream`. It seems that this stream only contains a baml fragment and does not have a header (that's why `System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_Header()` fails.)

So we need to tell the baml reader to read a baml fragment. This can be done be giving the reader an instance of `System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006ReaderSettings` where the `IsBamlFragment` property is`true`.

Unfortunately both the `Baml2006ReaderSettings` class and the appropriate constructor of `Baml2006Reader` are internal. So we need to resort to reflection:

```
private static string PresentationFrameworkAssemblyName = "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";

private static Baml2006Reader CreateBamlFragmentReader(MemoryStream substream, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext)
{
    var bamlSettingsType =
        Type.GetType(
            "System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006ReaderSettings, " + PresentationFrameworkAssemblyName);
    var settingsCtor =
        bamlSettingsType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    var bamlSettings = settingsCtor.Invoke(null);
    var isBamlFragmentProp = bamlSettingsType.GetProperty("IsBamlFragment",
                                                              BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                              BindingFlags.Instance);
    isBamlFragmentProp.SetValue(bamlSettings, true, null);

    var ctor = typeof (Baml2006Reader).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new[]
        {
            typeof (Stream),
            Type.GetType(
                "System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext, " + PresentationFrameworkAssemblyName),
                bamlSettingsType
            },
            null);

        return (Baml2006Reader)ctor.Invoke(new[] { substream, schemaContext, bamlSettings });
    }
```

usage:

```
var substream = reader.Value as MemoryStream;
if (substream != null)
{
    using (var subReader = CreateBamlFragmentReader(substream, reader.SchemaContext))
    {
        // continue reading with subReader
    }
}
```

I know this is rather fragile code and very hackish, but what the heck - it works (for me, currently)!